# ActiveRecord has_one / has_many within same Model/table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to figure out the best way to build my model.  Each user can have many balances, but I would like to enforce one balance of each currency per user. The application controls the record generation, so perhaps this is overkill. However, the question perplexed me, so I thought I'd ask the community.

If it makes sense to do, what would be the best way to build this?

My migration thus far:

```
class CreateBalances < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :balances do |t|
      t.decimal :amount
      t.integer :currency, default: 0, null: false  # this will be an enum in the model
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

TL;DR: one of each :currency per :user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your Balance model:

```
validates :currency, :uniqueness => true, :scope => user_id
```

What I think this says (and I could be wrong, so please take this with a grain of salt) is, "Make sure that this type of currency exists only once for this user." Failing that, you could also try a custom validation:

```
validates :unique_currency_balance_per_user

def unique_currency_balance_per_user
  Balance.where('id != ?', id)
         .where(:currency => currency, :user_id => user_id)
         .present?
end
```

There are also likely to be database-level constraints, but I am not yet aware of these.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a shot and let you know.